# how to store solvent in laboratory?

Tags: safety, solvents

I am organising chemicals and solvents in laboratory... being less specific ( as it would a big list of chemicals to provide here in my questions)... I wanted to know... how can we arrange solvents in lab as there would be acids like HCl, h2so4, and at the same time there are other solvents like aniline, ammonia, acetic acid, methanol, benzyl alcohol, esters, mercaptoethanol etc... kindly provide some tips regarding there arrangements.

Comment: What do you mean by arrange solvents?

Comment: Just put them in a shelf where they can’t fall down and are well vented. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hints on how to store solvents is not part of the scope of chemistry.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, storage may be (and likely is) location dependent because fire codes vary by country and jurisdiction.  Consult you local safety expert.

Answer (score 1):

All the chemicals should be segregated according to their reactive properties eg. Bases with bases, acids with acids, ionic salts with ionic salts, oxidizing agents by em self etc. The storage should be dry, we'll ventilated and everything labeled correctly and stored in a way that's practical to access without causing a hazard.